# Use of delay in ActiveJobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm trying to move my rails app's background processing library from DelayedJob to SideKiq. I went through the documentation for ActiveJobs and for Sidekiq, both of which suggest either a `app/workers` folder or `app/jobs` folder with the a `perform` method being written and further calling a class method such as `perform_async`.

However, on just adding the SideKiq gem, adding Sidekiq as the value for `config.active_job.queue_adapter` the following seems to work:
`delay(queue: queue_name , other_parameters ).method`

Where is delay defined? Is it an alias for perform? I tried searching for it in Rails' repo but to no avail.

Comment: Job.set(wait: 1.minute).perform(args)

Comment: @LuizE. thanks you for looking into this, but could you please elaborate? I'm not following :)

Comment: so, what I understood is that you want to use delays on your jobs. to use that, you should call the and set the wait param as I described. for example, you have a `MailerJob` that should wait 2 hours to send an email, you'll do `MailerJob.set(wait: 2.hours).perform(user.email)`

Comment: @LuizE. not exactly, the code that I have was configured to use DelayedJob and where it is needed a delay function (Which I'm using is how a job might be added into DelayedJob) with the queue name and other parameters are passed into said delay function, which is then chained to another method on which the DelayedJob is needed. 

The major source of confusion atm is that this legacy code that I'm dealing with and there's no documentation.

Comment: @LuizE. What I did do is that I kept all the code the same but just added the sidekiq gem, the yml config file and set the queue adapter for ActiveJob as Sidekiq. I did not expect the code to work, but somehow it seems to be working just fine with Sidekiq with no change in the code.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem, then...

Comment: @LuizE. okay, thank you again :)

Answer (score -1):

It's a delayed job method https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#queuing-jobs.

> Call .delay.method(params) on any object and it will be processed in
> the background.
>
> # without delayed_job @user.activate!(@device)
>
> # with delayed_job @user.delay.activate!(@device)

You'll need to migrate to using an ActiveJob object that wraps your method call.